# Check username exist in database firebase angularfire2

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

After registration and login,im asking user to create a profile.Right there i need to check whether users input exist in db,if not create profile.As you see data[0][4] = username in db.

with for loop im looping thorugh all profiles usernames to find username exist or not.right now it creates profile even username exists.

thanks

https://image.prntscr.com/image/qDttSENCRqaOncLmpXNuhA.png

```
createProfile(){

    this.allData=this.db.list(`/profile/`).valueChanges();
    this.allData.take(1).subscribe(data => {
      let data = data.map(this.getObjectWithoutKnowingKey);
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data[0][4]);
       console.log(data.length);
console.log(this.username);


for(var i=0;0<data.length;i++){

if(data[i][4] === this.username){
  console.log("username already exist");
return;

}

}
});

//if username exist dont execute this code below.

this.fire.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {


this.db.object(`profile/${auth.uid}/`).set({
username: this.username,
msgnumber: 0,
asd: 0,
avatar: this.avatar


});
this.db.object(`profile/${auth.uid}/inventory/`).set({

test: 1


}).then(() => this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage));



});






}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code I can see that you are iterating on the data. So that will just take your rather than try using `equalsTo` method of firebase. [Check it out.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query)